# Is it possible to keep disks indepndent while still virtually/visually spanning them?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, storage-spaces, jbod

I'm wondeirng is it possible to have a single volume containing muiltiple drives whereby the drives are basically treated like individual dirves so if one fails only the data stored on that particualr drive will fail.

I'm trying to implement a 3-2-1 backup scenario, but I'm bumping against not wainting raid (in either my first copy storage or my 2nd copy backup) because of the expense, but also wanting the convenience of having a pool of data to work with. In my head I imagine it being completely *fake*, as in it's just a visual thing for me within the file explorer but really under it all it's treating all the drives as individual drives and placing files on individual drives (maybe on the one with the most amount of space free, so they all build up evenly), and each drive would have a mirrored file struture so everything is easy to put togther. Effectively meaning windows just needs to visually show me D:Pictures and E:Pictures and F:Pitcures all in FakeDrive:Pictures. Maybe it would be like mounting all the drives to one virtual drive?

I'm not sure how it would actually work, or if it's even possible, but I'm finding it hard to find any info on such a situation. everything just has regular spanned volumes or Raid. Basically looking to avoid having to restore 24TB (2x12TB) from backup instead of just the 12TB from the failed drive.

Or maybe I'm missunderstanding how the spanned volume works, if I have two drives in a spanned volume, and in total it's 75% filled, so would that be one drive is 100% filled and the other 50% and one of teh drives failes, can I just replace that drive to then rebuild the span to gain access to the files on the drive that survived and then just retore the lost drive's data?

Also this is for on windows 10

Thanks

Comment: Use Symlinks to logically present a different view to the physical view on your disks.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the suggestion, though I don't think symlinks will work, from my understanding there are too many limitations that would make it fiddly, and potentially more awkward to deal with than just keeping the two drives completely separate altogether for my use-case. I did however just discover [StableBit's Drivepool](https://stablebit.com/drivepool) and it looks to be exactly what I was imagining, haven't gotten to test it out yet, but hopefully it'll do the job.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly... It's really hard trying to figure out what you are trying to accomplish....

You don't make  a RAID or SPAN at all. You just keep the 2 drives separate as E: and F: and manually distribute your files as you see fit over these 2 drives.
You make individuals backups of each.

That is the only way to achieve this: Only having to restore the drive that fails.
If you RAID or SPAN them together they effectively become a single unit and you have no control over what data is stored on which drive. So any backup needs encompass everything on the combined unit and be restored as such.

I think you are just discovering that there are no shortcuts if you want to have good backups. You have to do the whole thing properly or you might as well don't do them at all.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is wrong, and there is no indication on the OP he is trying to skimp on backups.